# I am getting the Invalid range error but yesterday i am able to access my data while Tapping on Contacts ,Leads,Junk buttons for a particular thing

Tags: flutter

Expanded(
child: GestureDetector(
child: Container(
width:
MediaQuery.of(context)
.size
.width *
0.30,
// margin:
//     EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
child: Wrap(
children: [
ClipRRect(
borderRadius:
BorderRadius
.circular(
36.0),
child: Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets
.only(
top: 10.0,
bottom:
10.0,
left: 6.0,
right: 6.0),
decoration:
const BoxDecoration(
color: Color(
0xFFD7EFD2),
boxShadow: [
BoxShadow(
color: Color(
0xFFD7EFD2),
offset: Offset(
3.0,
6.0),
blurRadius:
10.0),
],
),
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets
.symmetric(
horizontal:
5.0),
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment:
MainAxisAlignment
.start,
crossAxisAlignment:
CrossAxisAlignment
.center,
children: [
Container(
padding:
EdgeInsets.zero,
margin:
EdgeInsets.zero,
// alignment:
// Alignment
//     .centerLeft,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
.18,
child: Text(
'Leads'
.toUpperCase(),
style: const TextStyle(
fontSize: 10.0,
fontFamily: "OpenSans",
color: Colors.black,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
),
Expanded(
child:
Text(
mapDataLead[collectionList[index]["Name"]]
.toString(),
style: const TextStyle(
fontSize:
10.0,
color:
Colors.black,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontFamily: "OpenSans"),
)),
],
),
)),
),
],
),
),
onTap: () {
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) =>
ContactListTabScreen(
"Collection:" +
collectionList[index]
[
"Name"] +
"|",
"Leads")));
},
),
),

Comment: Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => ContactListTabScreen( "Collection:" + collectionList[index] [ "Name"] + "|", "Leads"))); getting error on this particular line i am new not finding the solution m stucked here from 5-6 hours........Error:RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: I think you have list of data and onTap each item new page opens, so here index is the position of that widget on which you are tapping.

Comment: Please format your code for proper readability. 1) open code in editor and format 2) paste into stackoverflow 3) sectct code from stackoverflow console and press '{  }' icon. again check before submitting.

Comment: Kindly add more content about the issue you are facing, and format the code properly for readability.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: want to hide leading icon of appbar while navigate from bottom navigation to the particular screen but if i want to navigate to the same screen by button on tap function i want that leading icon how can i manage it

Answer (score 0):

your question is so vague!

give some more details
for example where your data came from or what exactly you want to do

and copy the piece of code the right way

Comment: I solved it i am sorry i am a beginner but i have another query please help me .....want to hide leading icon of appbar while navigate from bottom navigation to the particular screen but if i want to navigate to the same screen by button on tap function i want that leading icon how can i manage it please help..

Comment: it's too hard to explain what you should do in this way unless you give me a sample code